# NSThread detachNewThreadSelector???? uh?

Tags: objective-c, nsthread, nsrunloop

I was looking through the Threading Programming which I have to say it's really good. Specially I was looking on [How to configure Port-based input sources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1) for running loops. And I see this piece of code

```
// Detach the thread. Let the worker release the port.
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(LaunchThreadWithPort:)
           toTarget:[MyWorkerClass class] withObject:myPort];
```

I had understood everything 'til that. What is that function doing?, What is "LaunchThreadWithPort", What does "MyWorkerClass" standFor?.

I lack a bit of knowledge on @selectors, but It's not my main question. I really didn't understand a word about that function and what is doing there.

Thanks to anyone who replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code basically tells the system to create a new thread that executes `[[MyWorkerClass class] launchThreadWithPort: myPort]`. The thread runs until this method returns.

Comment: And the method who launched the thread, continues the execution? or does it stop 'til the thread returns?

Comment: Yes, the method that calls this continues to run.